# What's the purpose of MSAL stateMismatch

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

What's the purpose of `msal:stateMismatch`?  How should it be handled?

`msal` is broadcasting the event `msal:stateMismatch` after being redirected back from login.microsoftonline.com.

The only information I could find was in spec.ts on the GitHub site: `stateMismatch broadcast when state does not match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get this when the state returned by the STS is different from the one sent by MSAL. MSAL sends a state associated with each request to STS and expects the reply to be consistent. Someone could intercept a request and use it elsewhere. If the request is invoked by an external URL, anyone can invoke it using fake data while MSAL is waiting for a response from STS.

According to the [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html): opaque value used to maintain state between the request and the callback, CSRF mitigation is done by cryptographically binding the value of this parameter with a browser cookie. 
Here's more info that you might find interesting on [CSRF attacks and the state parameter](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/mitigate-csrf-attacks).

Comment: thanks for the info @Jenny.  The links are very helpful.  STS = Security Token Service.  The state value is being generated by msal, stored locally, and then compared with the returned value.  I'm using msal 0.2.1.  Upgrading to msal 0.2.4 would solve this issue?

Comment: @DeanB_Develop upgrading is always good. Give it a try and if the issue continues, open an issue in the [MSAL JS library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues) and they can take a look.